# chrome cache don't work in some pc

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I have a web application and two computer, both with win7 and chrome *v56.0.2924.76*.

and in the app it need several js file. when I request the resources, it response with the same response headers

```
Cache-Control:max-age=7200, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Mon, 06 Mar 2017 09:40:11 GMT
Expires:Mon, 06 Mar 2017 11:40:11 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=496
Last-Modified:Wed, 22 Feb 2017 18:47:28 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0
```

in one desktop, everything works fine, and it get all js file from cache, while in another desktop,**most are fine** while some are still getting from the remote.

the difference is: on the not cached desktop the request has requester header with all detail like `Accept/Accept-Encoding/Cookie/etc.`
and on the cached desktop have the request header say 
`Provisional headers are shown`

I think since one of them is working, the remote server is fine, the problems is in the chrome side, while they both are the same version, I want to know anything else can I check.

Comment: Go to Network tab and make sure "Disable Caching" is not checked

Comment: Thank you for  your reply, Yes of course the Disable Caching is unchecked in the network panel, and as I said some are cached. that is what I feel wierd

Comment: Some update, after looking into the chrome://cache/,  I can see the file under my app's host don't cached, while in another working computer, it is cached, is there any configuration to control which file to cache or not in chrome? since the response are some

Comment: I don't know any file specific cache setting in chrome. In developer tools go to settings page (not chrome settings) there is an option "disable caching while dev tool window is open" That might be checked on one of your computers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the root cause, "not working one" don't installed the correct certification so that the "not working one"'s https is not secure, and there is a warning before the url say "not secure", and chrome seems not cache the not secured content so the files are not cached, after I installed the correct certification it works fine now.